# Вернуть в javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне в методе вернуть вот это

```
{
  "datasets": [
    {
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 255, 42, 0.1)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)",
      "borderWidth": 2,
      "data": [
        500,
        1000,
        50
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

если делаю return то куча ошибок вылазит ...

Comment: Думаю вам стоит приложить в вопросе ваш код, который не работает и где ошибки. И указать что за ошибки и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так хотели?

```js
function returnSomething(){
return {
  "datasets": [
      {
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 255, 42, 0.1)",
        "borderColor": "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)",
        "borderWidth": 2,
        "data": [
          500,
          1000,
          50
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

console.log(returnSomething())
```

или у вас другие ожидания?